# Converting between LINQ expression types

Tags: .net, linq

Does anyone know of a tool which converts between the 'types' of linq query expression?  ie:

a) var foo = from c in customers select...

b) var foo = customer .Where(...

I'm more familiar with a), but to use dynamic linq b) is required so it'd be nice to easily convert all my existing queries.

I've had a bit of a look at Linqer and LinqPad but can't see such a function - perhaps its in there somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Too much trouble.  Just convert them as needed to use Dynamic LINQ, otherwise leave them alone.  From now on, use the fluent (method) style.

Comment: Both forms are equivalent.  It's just a syntactic difference.  One uses the query syntax and the other makes direct calls.  The compiler just converts the query syntax to the other for you.  Just analyze what each is doing and make the appropriate calls.

Comment: Is there any way to see that lambda syntax the compiler generates during it's process?

Comment: @Glinkot: Any tool that can decompile IL code back to whatever language could do that.  Reflector is one such tool that could do that (provided you set the optimizations to .NET 2.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely in LINQPad - but you only see it when querying against databases:

[image: LINQPad Screenshots]

You even get the SQL and IL that was created.

Comment: Nice!  I'm a registered LinqPadder so will definitely make use!  Thanks!

Comment: @Glinkot - I use it for all sorts of "scratch-pad" coding. It's an awesome product.